# statsvn support for users with "." in name

Tags: svn, configuration-files, properties-file, statsvn

With StatSVN it's possible to define information about user(s) in a configuration file.  An example from the documentation is here:

```
 # Example
 user.benoitx.realName=Benoit Xhenseval
 user.benoitx.url=http://www.xhenseval.com/benoit
 user.benoitx.image=http://www.xhenseval.com/benoit/bx-avatar.jpg
 user.benoitx.email=
 user.benoitx.twitterUsername=benoitx
 user.benoitx.twitterUserId=18722145
 user.benoitx.twitterIncludeHtml=true
 user.benoitx.twitterIncludeFlash=true
```

However, what happens if the username has a "." in it?  Any clever ways to achieve this?  For example:  `john.doe`:

```
 user.john.doe.realName=Benoit Xhenseval
 user.john.doe.url=http://www.xhenseval.com/benoit
 user.john.doe.image=http://www.xhenseval.com/benoit/bx-avatar.jpg
 user.john.doe.email=
 user.john.doe.twitterUsername=benoitx
 user.john.doe.twitterUserId=18722145
 user.john.doe.twitterIncludeHtml=true
 user.john.doe.twitterIncludeFlash=true
```

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion to this was to rename the user on the system to a username that doesn't have a `.` in it.  problem solved.